# Работа с Ajax ( Выпадающий список)

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2, yii

существует у меня не большая проблема, которую очень прошу вас помочь мне решить.
Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на select , где храниться id , передавалось это значение в Ajax скрипт. И, например, при выборе какого - либо поля выпадающего списка, в консоль передавалось значение этого id-шника.

```
(function () {
    $(".changeTemplate").change(function () {
        var id = $(".changeTemplate").val()
    })
    $.ajax({
        url: urlToGetTemplates/+'id', //Правильно ли тут?
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        complete: function () {
            console.log('succes');
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(id);
        }
    });
});

<select class="changeTemplate">
    <option>Выберите шаблон</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($templates as $templ) {
        echo "<option value='".$templ['_id']."'>".$templ['title']."</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var urlToGetTemplates = <?=json_encode($this->createUrl('selectOneTemplate'));?>
</script>
```

Comment: Вызов `$.ajax` поместите во внутрь функции обратного вызова `change`

Comment: Не помогло , все равно консоль пустая

Comment: url: urlToGetTemplates+'/'+id апострофы вокруг id уберите